# What happens when a JFrame is resized?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, repaint

I am curious as to what happens exactly in Java when a JFrame is resized.

I am asking this because of an issue I am having with adding a component to my bigCOntainer (of type JPanel) inside the JFrame. I want to add something when the user performs a certain action but the component doesn't become visibly added until the JFrame is resized somehow.

I discovered this when I was doing some experimenting trying to get the new component to show up; I called myJFrame.pack(). As a secondary question I would like to know what pack() does, both generally and specific to resizing. The Java Documentation makes it sound like it will resize every component to its preferred size. My solution, if I decide to use pack() in my implementation to display new components is to always set a preferred size. Can anyone attest to this being an accepted programming practice? It sure seems like a good idea.

I also tried repaint() to get the new component to show up but that did not work.

Comment: *Why* is the code adding new components after the GUI is visible?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The program I am writing is for experience. However, I am adding a label after a user loads a file as a reminder to the user of what is going on in the program.

Comment: *"..adding a label after a user loads a file"*  Add the label to the GUI at start-up with no text.  When there is a message for the user, set a text (possibly with a one-shot Swing `Timer` to clear the field).  Also look at tool tips.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have tooltips. I don't want the label added at start up. That violates the premise of the post, but thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to  call `revalidate()` and *then* `repaint()` on the container that gets components added or removed during run-time.

`revalidate()` tells the container's layout managers to re-layout the components it contains, and this is what is missing from your code. Without this request, the layouts don't change, and you don't see the changes until you re-size the GUI, which pretty much does the same thing.

Note that if you're adding components to the GUI on start-up, then the solution is to call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` to the top-level container only ***after*** all components have been added.

For specifics about say what `pack()` does, do what we all do -- read the source code.